# How to detect safari browser in mvc 5 application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, user-agent

I have a mvc 5 application (not core but .net framework) where I am trying to add a check for Safari browser only but the issue is I am getting all browsers installed on my pc when i get User-Agent from request.

I am getting the following value:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36

But actually I am calling through chrome. Here is how I am getting the value

```
var userAgent = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
```

I've also tried getting the value from header (which is the same thing) e.g Request.Headers["User-Agent"] but still same result.

How can I add a check for Safari browser?

Comment: Can you use Javascript on the client-side?

Comment: No, i can only do it on backend side

Comment: Try to check filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.browser?view=netframework-4.8